# Increase Stack Size on Windows (GCC)

Tags: windows, gcc, compiler-construction, linker, stack

Is there a way to increase the stack size of a Windows application at compile/link time with GCC?

Comment: Could any one explain me what does Increasing stack size mean? stack frame is portion occupied by a function on stack. and stack is decided by operating system right? How does `editbin` helps it? I'm confused!

Comment: @claws Late to the party, but this might give some insight: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based_memory_allocation. Also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could run [editbin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/editbin-reference?view=msvc-170) after linking.

Comment: I definitely could - and this appears to be what I'll inevitably have to do - but I was looking for a way to do it at link time. Thanks though.

Answer (score 22):

IIRC, In GCC you can provide the --stack,[bytes] parameter to ld.

E.g.

```
gcc -Wl,--stack,16777216 -o file.exe file.c
```

To have a stack of 16MiB, I think that the default size is 8MiB.

Comment: This is what I was originally looking for. Unfortunately, I haven't had any luck with this on Windows.  Have you?

Comment: +1 This does indeed work when I tried it on gcc 4.5.2. Without this switch, compiled programs start segfaulting with static array sizes ~500k. After applying this switch, I was able to increase the size all the way up to 3million elements without incident.

Comment: In CMake, this looks something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43342925) and it works for me.

Answer (score 2):

There are two stack sizes in Windows. The initially commited size, and the total reserved size. You can set both with a STACKSIZE statement in a .def file.

Answer (score 0):

When creating threads you use the dwStackSize paremater, but I'm not sure how to change the size for the main thread, this indicates its in the exe's header, so it may be an option for the compiler/linker, else you need to find the relevant part of the header and change it yourself.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686774(VS.85).aspx