# Should I use vectors instead of arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

If I have a **fixed number** of elements of class MyClass, should I use arrays or vectors?, ie:

```
MyClass* myArray[];
```

or

```
std::vector<MyClass*> myVector;
```

?

Comment: Probably `std::array`. It depends on how many elements you have. If there are too many, you may have to use `std::vector`.

Comment: If the elements are managed by the current instanceor in the current scope use `std::array<MyClass, N>` or `std::array<MyClass*, N>` otherwise.

Comment: Also consider to use vectors of the class instead of vectors of pointers. A pointer has nothing to do there except you are doing polymorphism or sharing ownership, cases where smart pointers are far better than a naked C pointer.

Comment: `vector<MyClass>` is much less headache than `vector<MyClass *>`, if you can meet your requirements that way. (same goes for `array`)

Comment: Why the pointers in `std::vector<MyClass*>` and `MyClass*[]`?

Comment: If you must use pointers to `MyClass`, you should at least use `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @Jefffrey I don't know. Maybe just because I have sent it somewhere. I use * every time a have public vars in my classes that are going to be accessed from another classes. For example, if my class Player has a vector of Pieces that is going to be accessed by Board, then I make Piece* a pointer. I understand, maybe incorrectely, the no-pointers as data local to the current scope, and I use pointers to "more important" less local data.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Why does * give more problems? I don't fully understand the difference.

Comment: @Tananan, a value of type `T *` says "over there, there is a `T`". If your vector is full of these , then you still have to create all the `T`'s somewhere else, so you can set your vector up to contain pointers to them.  So now you not only have to manage your vector but you also have to manage where the `T`'s are being stored, and who is responsible for creating new ones and deleting old ones. This gets hairy if your code includes the possibility of handing out a pointer to another function to operate on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `std::array` or raw arrays for a small, static number of elements.

If you have a lot of elements (more than say 100kb), you hog the stack and are asking for stack corruption / overflow. In that case, or if the number of elements can only be known at runtime, use `std::vector`.

Comment: Which is the difference between std::array and raw arrays? Isn't std::array just the same as array but specifying the namespace?

Comment: That would probably make a good separate question. For starters though, there's http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array

Answer (score 3):

if you know the number in compile time - use static `array`.

if the number is dynamic (obtained from the user) - `vector` is much better to save you the hurdle of managing the memory

Answer (score 2):

"Fixed" has two meanings in this context. The usual one is *set once, never change*, such as a value read from input. This value is known at runtime and requires dynamic allocation on the heap. Your options are a C-style array with *new* or a vector; it is highly recommended you use a vector.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int size;
    std::cin >> size;
    int *myArray = new int[size];
    std::vector<int> myVector(size);
}
```

"Fixed" can also mean a *compile-time constant*, meaning it is constant for any run of the program. You can use a C-style array or a C++ array (automatic memory allocation on the stack).

```
#include <array>
int main() {
    const int size = 50;
    int myArray[size];
    std::array<int, size> myArray;
}
```

These are faster, but your program needs to have access to sufficient stack memory, which is something you can change in your project settings. See [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15329281/how-big-is-the-stack-memory-for-a-certain-program-and-are-there-any-compiler-fl) for more info. If the size of the array is really big, you may want to consider allocating on the Heap anyway (vector).

Comment: +1 but *"static memory allocation (stack)."* delete these words. Could be confusing with static storage duration.

Comment: *automatic* is the Standard term for such allocation

Comment: Edited. Hopefully it is now less confusing and more correct.