# Increasing stack size for C program in Clion

Tags: c, windows, cygwin, clion

How can one increase the maximum size of a stack for C program that has a deep recursive call? Is there any config for the project where one can specify the stack or heap size for executables?

Comment: If this is on Linux or other *nix OS then you can set the stack size from within your code - see [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2284691/253056) for code.

Comment: I'm doing it on Windows, with Cygwin environment

Comment: I believe cygwin also supports `getrlimit`/`setrlimit`, so I suggest giving it a try.

Comment: I tried copypasting the code in the answer and running recursive function in the end of main, but nothing changed.

Comment: You may need to adjust `kStackSize` of course - how much stack space do you think that your program needs ?

Comment: Initial thread stack size is set by the linker.  You can ask the linker to increase it at build time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on the OP's own answer, the following three CMake commands all work for me on Windows with MinGW/GCC (replace `<target>` with what you entered into `add_executable()`):

```
target_link_libraries(<target> PRIVATE "-Wl,--stack,10000000")
```

OR

```
set_target_properties(<target> PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS -Wl,--stack,10000000)
```

OR

```
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -Wl,--stack,10000000")
```

According to the [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/index.html), each of these should just add linker flags, not replace any that are already set.

In Visual Studio, you should replace `-Wl,--stack,` with `/STACK:` in each of these according to [this thread](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17572) and others. For example:

```
target_link_libraries(<target> PRIVATE "/STACK:10000000")
```

Answer (score 8):

I solved the problem by adding following linker flag in project's `CMakeList.txt`

```
MATH(EXPR stack_size "16 * 1024 * 1024") # 16 Mb
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,--stack,${stack_size}")
```

Comment: This worked for me too. Note that this can also be done using `target_link_libraries()` or `set_target_properties()` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55989674).

Comment: @GumbyTheGreen, Nice solution. Have you considered posting it as an answer, so that I can accept it, instead of selfishly accepting my own solution :)

Comment: Done. It's never too late to change your selfish ways... :) 
No, I actually found your answer helpful as well and am now using that math expression in my own script.

Answer (score 1):

To check initial stack size

```
peflags -x <binary>
```

to set size

```
peflags -x<size> <binary>
```

As reference `peflags --help` and
https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2013-08/msg00318.html

Answer (score 0):

on macos (os x) or linux use

`-stack_size` like so:

`set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,-stack_size,4000000")`

- notice: the number is interpreted as hex