# Cmake change stack size

Tags: visual-studio, gcc, cmake, stack, stack-size

Is there a way to change stack size from the *Cmake* ?
I only found one [forum thread](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-commits/Week-of-Mon-20131014/191537.html) mentioning `CMAKE_CXX_STACK_SIZE` but I couldn't find the documentation for this command. Ideally the command should work for both *Visual Studio C++* and *gcc*.

Answer (score 10):

I don't have VS at the moment, but the following three CMake commands all work for me on MinGW/GCC (replace `<target>` with what you entered into `add_executable()`):

```
target_link_libraries(<target> PRIVATE "-Wl,--stack,10000000")
```

OR

```
set_target_properties(<target> PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS -Wl,--stack,10000000)
```

OR

```
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -Wl,--stack,10000000")
```

Note that according to the [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/index.html), each of these should just add linker flags, not replace any that are already set.

In VS, it looks like you should replace `-Wl,--stack,` with `/STACK:` (more on this below) and use an if/else to have different commands for each compiler.

Regarding `CMAKE_CXX_STACK_SIZE`, [this thread](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17572), which is worth a read, says the command is

> in the implementation of the VS generator for historical reasons but is not intended as a first-class way to set the stack size. Instead just pass `/STACK:`... as a linker flag using `target_link_libraries`, or the `LINK_FLAGS` target property, or in `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS`...

Such a command can actually be seen on [the page](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-commits/Week-of-Mon-20131014/191537.html) linked in your post (not sure if you saw it) as well as in [this one](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-commits/Week-of-Mon-20160829/386716.html):

```
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} /STACK:10000000")
```

Comment: minor note: when used with Visual Studio 2019 at any rate, the actual linker command-line will have `/STACK:"10000000"`. ie, with the stack size in quotes. however this seems to be fine because the corresponding .vcxproj will have the value in this form: `<StackReserveSize>10000000</StackReserveSize>`.

Comment: Also it looks like VS enforces a minimum of 0x40000 bytes, as measured at runtime by `GetCurrentThreadStackLimits()`.